# How to resolve this error: MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am follwoing a tutorial on mongoose and wrote this code in script.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const User = require("./User");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/testdb");

run();

async function run() {
    const user = await User.create({name: "xyz", age: 26});
    console.log(user);
}





console.log("Hi")
```

This is my code at User.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

I am writing the exact same code as shown in the tutorial, for him it's working but for me I am getting the following error:
node script.js
Hi
const err = new MongooseError(message);
^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\MongooseDB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

Node.js v18.16.1

I have realised that the code involving the async function is causing some problem because without it the code runs well.

I have realised that the code involving the async function is causing some problem because without it the code runs well. I am scratching my head around on this from the last 4 hours, but no help.